# redland rapper/libraptor2 running out of memory on large RDF file

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf, redland

I'm trying to parse the Turtle dump from the [Freebase Data Dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) using libraptor2 [version 2-2.0.10], and my program runs out of memory. So, I tried using the "rapper" program and the results are same (runs out of memory):

```
#  raptor2-2.0.10/bin/rapper -i turtle -I - -o turtle -O - freebase-rdf-2013-06-02-00-00.ttl > /dev/null

rapper: Parsing URI file:///...ttl with parser turtle and base URI -
rapper: Serializing with serializer turtle
Killed
```

I watch the memory consumption, and it goes upto 4GB and then dies.
How do I limit the memory consumption for libraptor/rapper?

Comment: This is a good question (and with a useful answer).  Note though, that "Is there any other opensource rdf parsing libraries that doesn't suffer this problem ?" is asking for libraries, and "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".  It would also be nice to have included a link to the data, so that others can try to reproduce this behavior.  All that said, this is a _good_ question, and **thank you** for including the exact error message exactly as it appears!

Answer (score 1):

Likely it is not parsing that is causing your problem. The parser reads the input one token at a time and when it can find a triple, it emits it to the serializer. However, serializing *to* turtle requires a lot of memory. The serializer first builds the whole graph in-memory and only when all triples have been added, the graph is written out as turtle.

So, change the output format from graph-oriented turtle to some triple-oriented syntax such as `ntriples`.

---

Updated after comments.

Since the memory issue is still there with counting mode which throws away the triples once parsed, it's definitely also a parser memory issue.

Not sure what you ultimately want to do with the data, but here's something that might help.
Note that freebase data format is line-oriented "ntriples with turtle namespaces" so it's relatively straightforward to process down to more manageable chunks usign simple text file processing tools:

1. Preserve `@prefix` declarations from file header to all chunks.
2. Cut data at triple i.e. linefeed boundary.

Comment: laalto, thanks. I'm not so familiar with all details of RDF yet. My plan is to insert all "subject, predicate, object" tuple to my own DB. As you suggested I tried to convert ttl to ntriples, but the program is still running out of memory,# raptor2-2.0.10/install/bin/rapper -i turtle -I - -o ntriples -O - freebase-rdf-2013-06-02-00-00.ttl

Comment: it runs out of memory even if I ask "rapper" to just count the number of tripples  (using option --count) in the turtle file.